# is it possible to hide a Node in the neo4j browser once it has been shown

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to hide a node in the browser once it has been 'opened'.

In any more than a trivial graph it gets quite cluttered with all the relationships, when all I want is to focus on the most important nodes/relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop seeing relationships that your query did not return, you can switch the "AUTO-COMPLETE" button at the bottom of the pane to "OFF".

But there is no way (other than modifying your query) to turn off the display of nodes that you had asked for.